# Can't Convert an Int Array to ASCII

Tags: java, arrays, ascii

to the point.
I don't know what make my function error but here when i want to convert an int Array to ASCII character, i got some errors which says

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 51529974 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 30MB

I think my function doesn't right enough to convert it.
Here is my function :

```
public static String[] DectoASCII(int[] resultXORDec,int jumKat) {
    int length = jumKat;

    String ASCIIfromDec[] = new String[jumKat];

    for(int i=0;i<jumKat;i++) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; i--) {
            builder.append((char) ((resultXORDec[j] >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF));
        }
        ASCIIfromDec[i]=builder.toString();
        Log.d("ascifrom",ASCIIfromDec[i]);
    }
    return ASCIIfromDec;
}
```

}

Please master, help me. Is there any other way to convert int (Decimal) to ASCII code? 
Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess the `j` index does not change in this loop:

```
for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; i--) {
builder.append((char) ((resultXORDec[j] >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF));
}
```

thus you have an infinite loop, so `builder` gets bigger and bigger.

Comment: Yea i think this is the problem, maybe the `i--` was meant to be `j--`

Comment: okaay thanks sir, it can run properly now. But i got error on the result.

The result of string builder just display ???? when i Log.d to it.
Is there any way to convert stringbuilder to a normal String?

Comment: You just do it by using `toString` method. Another problem is what you actually put in `resultXORDec`.